# JavaScript: Object destructuring dynamically via computed keys

Tags: javascript, destructuring, computed-properties

I'm trying to write a curried function dissoc, that takes in a prop and an object and removes the key and its value from the object.

Here is the code that works:

```
const dissoc = prop => obj => {
  const result = {};
  for (let p in obj) {
    result[p] = obj[p];
  }
  delete result[prop];
  return result;
};
```

Now, I thought this could be written more concise by using [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), destructuring and the rest operator:

```
const dissoc = prop => ({ [prop], ...obj}) => obj
```

But this code throws with:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

So I tried:

```
const dissoc = prop => ({ prop, ...obj}) => obj
```

which computes, but just returns the object without the prop.

Is there a way to dynamically destructure and / or simplify this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a target variable, for example an underscore as sign for an unused variable/placeholder.

```
const dissoc = prop => ({ [prop]: _, ...obj}) => obj
```

Javascript does not have the concept of using variable variables, like PHP with `$$variable`, where the value of `$variable` is taken as variable. In this case, you need another variable, because of the [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and without a real variable, it does not work.

Maybe worth a read: [Object property assignment pattern [YDKJS: ES6 & Beyond]](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern)

Comment: Wow that was fast. I can accept your answer in 12 minutes. Thank you very much.